# boost::assign, ptr_map, and polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a mapping of enum type to factory object, but can't get code that seems valid to compile on MSVC9 (**Using C++03**):

```
namespace detail {
    class INoteCreator
    {
    public:
        virtual ~INoteCreator() {}
        virtual Note* create( DBHANDLE ) const {}
        virtual Note* clone( DBHANDLE, Note const& ) const {}
    };

    template<class T>
    class NoteCreator : public INoteCreator
    {
    public:
        virtual Note* create( DBHANDLE h ) const
        {
            return new T( h );
        }

        virtual Note* clone( DBHANDLE h, Note const& n ) const
        {
            return new T( h, static_cast<T const&>(n) );
        }
    };

    typedef boost::ptr_map<Note::Type, INoteCreator> Container;
    static Container mapping = boost::assign::map_list_of<Note::Type, INoteCreator*>
        (Note::COMPOSITE_NOTE, new NoteCreator<Note>())
        (Note::HTML_NOTE, new NoteCreator<HtmlNote>())
        (Note::MIME_NOTE, new NoteCreator<MimeNote>())
        ;
}
```

The errors I'm getting:

> error C2039: 'base' : is not a member of
>   'stlpd_std::priv::_DBG_iter<_Container,_Traits>'
>
> error C2512:
>   'boost::ptr_container_detail::ref_pair' : no appropriate default
>   constructor available

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working and possibly share a fix or workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map_list_of` doesn't work with Boost.PtrContainer. You can't use the list_of syntax here; you have to use [`ptr_map_insert()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#ptr_push_back) instead. It has the advantage of being exception-safe, which your current code isn't.

Of course this isn't compatible with your static initialization ... I don't really have a good idea here except `boost::call_once` (from the Boost.Thread). There's `ptr_list_of`, but it doesn't support `ptr_map`. You could try writing your own, it's not that complicated.